# edit array from another activity

Tags: java, android, arrays

When trying to edit a custom `arraylist` from another `Activity` the application force closed.

Arraylist in `MainActivity`:

```
ArrayList<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
```

Another `Activity`:

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
main.contacts.get(position).contactname=x;
main.contacts.get(position).contactnumber=x;
```

How can I edit an arraylist from another activity?

Logcat:

```
09-08 22:53:40.415    1760-1760/com.example.amir_p.contacts E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.amir_p.contacts, PID: 1760
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.amir_p.contacts/com.example.amir_p.contacts.ContactInfo}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3577)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3620)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.example.amir_p.contacts.ContactInfo.onActivityResult(ContactInfo.java:53)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3573)
```

Comment: How is your contacts array initialized? I mean, where do you add items?

Comment: you need to provide more context on what you are trying to do, where you are trying to do it and why you want to do it

Comment: im sure that my arraylist is correct because i add some items to it in my Mainactivity and list shows them and my contacts.java is:

Comment: public String contactname;
    public String contactnumber;

Comment: @tyczj i want to edit one of my contacts in application with this code from another activity so i create an object to access classes and arrays in mainactivity

Comment: What you are trying to do, you should not try to do. It's bad Java and it's very bad Android.

Comment: so whats your suggestion for me? :| @AutonomousApps

Comment: @Amir_P could you provide more explanation for what you're trying to do and why you're trying to do it this way? I am echoing @tyczj here. From a Java standpoint, normal encapsulation guidelines apply: you shouldn't be accessing another class's members directly;  you should access them only throw getters and setters. From an Android perspective, you don't normally store model information in an `Activity` for another `Activity` to access.

Comment: ok suppose i have another class just for arraylist and i want to edit it. how to do that?

Comment: Did anything pop in the error log when the application force closed?

Comment: logcat added @NathanielFord

Comment: According to your `logcat`, it seems your actual problem is that `.get(position)` fails because there is nothing in that array...

Comment: ive uploaded my project if you can edit it and upload again for me @NathanielFord

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4f8XcF13wgEZlhMZVJORGN4Ums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

## 1

You can't instantiate an activity:

```
new MainActivity();
```

Activities must be launched from an Intent like so:

```
thisActivity.startActivity( new Intent( NextActivity.class ) );
```

## 2

If you want two activities to share a list, then you must instantiate that list in a greater scope, like the Application scope by creating a custom application class or creating a singleton.

Singleton:

```
public final class MySingleton {
    private static final MySingleton SELF = new MySingleton();

    private List<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
    private boolean didContacts

    private MySingleton() {
        // Don't want anyone else constructing the singleton.
    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        return SELF;
    }

    public List<Contacts> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Now in any activity you like you may get the list

```
MySingleton.getInstance().getContacts()
```

Just be careful of concurrent modification.

**Amendment due to a request in comments**

It was stated in the comments that you want to change one activity from another.  You must realize only one activity is active at a time and so you *SHOULD NOT* do that, regardless of whether or not you could hack it.  I would normally recommend a listener but a listener wont work in this case since only one Activity Another way to do this would be to have some in-memory state that lives outside the activity (maybe the singleton) that the activities can respond to when they regain focus.

**Pseudo code**

```
ActivityB {
  onClick() {
    MySingleton.getInstance().getContacts().add( theContact );
  }
}

ActivityA {
    onResume() {
        // consider contacts may have changed and redraw
        listViewAdapter.clear();
        listViewAdapter.addAll( MySingleton.getInstance().getContacts() );
    }    
}
```

Comment: PS - you could also use startActivityForResult which allows thisActivity to request nextActivity to return a numeric result which can be used to tell thisActivity what to do (such as add an entry to a list) but that's going to be pretty tough and messy.

Comment: This is very basic stuff.  I recommend you walk through an Android tutorial.

Comment: i cant use startactivityforresult because my activity is starting from another subsidiary activity and arraylist is in mainactivity :D (my english is bad so ...)

Comment: Like I said in my answer.  Create a Singleton (like the example I gave you) then both activities may access the ArrayList within the singleton.

Comment: i do that and it works great but i have another method in mainactivity that i cant use it in singleton. thats setlistadapter and i need to call it from another activitys. how to do that?

Comment: @Amir_P what you are trying to do is considered very bad.  You must realize that only one activity is active at a time.  So you can't do what you're asking.  However, you can change some persisted or app-scoped state and the other activity can respond to the state when it re-gains focus.  I will append an example to my answer above.

Comment: @Amir_P okay I've updated the answer.  At this point, you should be able to put it all together, if not -- I dont think I can help you without sitting next to you ;)  Good luck.

Comment: mu reputation is 13 and i cant upvote until it reachs 15 :(

Comment: Amazing solution. Helped me alot. Thank you very much!